# Vue Sidebar Transition with tailwind leaving not works

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to get it work sidebar related to [this link](https://tailwindui.com/components/ecommerce/components/store-navigation)

Entering works but leaving not works on both overlay and slide back.

```html
<div class="fixed inset-0 flex z-40 lg:hidden" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" v-show="mobileMenuOpen">
    
    <transition 
      enter-class="opacity-0"
      enter-active-class="transition-opacity ease-linear duration-300" 
      enter-to-class="opacity-100"  
      leave-class="opacity-0"
      leave-active-class="transition-opacity ease-linear duration-300" 
      leave-to-class="opacity-0"  
    >
    <div class="fixed inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-25" aria-hidden="true"  v-show="mobileMenuOpen" @click="closeMobileMenu"></div>

    </transition>

    
    <transition 
      enter-active-class="transition ease-in-out duration-300 transform" 
      enter-class="-translate-x-full"
      enter-to-class="translate-x-0"  
      leave-class="translate-x-0"
      leave-active-class="transition ease-in-out duration-300 transform" 
      leave-to-class="-translate-x-full" 
      appear 

    > sidebar code
```

Answer (score 0):

Your starting state for leave is `opacity-0` try changing it to `opacity-100`

```
...
leave-class="opacity-100"
...
```

> v-leave: Starting state for leave. Added immediately when a leaving transition is triggered, removed after one frame.